# python, and unicode stderr

Tags: python, unicode, stderr

I used an anonymous pipe to capture all stdout,and stderr then print into a richedit, it's ok when i use wsprintf ,but the python using multibyte char that really annoy me. how can I convert all these output to unicode?

**UPDATE 2010-01-03:**

Thank you for the reply, but it seems the `str.encode()` only worked with `print xxx` stuff, if there is an error during the `py_runxxx()`, my redirected stderr will capture the error message in multibyte string, so is there a way can make python output it's message in unicode way? And there seems to be an available solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956142/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-python).

I'll try it later.

Answer (score 9):

First, please remember that on Windows console may not fully support Unicode.

The example below does make python output to `stderr` and `stdout` using **UTF-8**. If you want you could change it to other encodings.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import codecs, sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

print sys.getdefaultencoding()

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)

print "This is an Е乂αmp١ȅ testing Unicode support using Arabic, Latin, Cyrillic, Greek, Hebrew and CJK code points."
```

Comment: Nice! Although replacing stdout and stderr was not necessary in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Unicode in python either by marking strings as Unicode (ie: `u'Hello World'`) or by using the encode() method that all strings have.

**Eg.** assuming you have a Unicode string, aStringVariable:

```
aStringVariable.encode('utf-8')
```

will convert it to UTF-8. 'utf-16' will give you UTF-16 and 'ascii' will convert it to a plain old ASCII string.

For more information, see:

- [Tutorial - Unicode Strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)
- [Python String Methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: 1. It is a bad practice to shadow builtin names (`str()` in this case). 2. `.encode()` should be called on Unicode string and not on byte-string.

Comment: That was just a bad choice for a variable name. I've changed it to something more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

`wsprintf`?

This seems to be a "C/C++" question rather than a Python question.

The Python interpreter always writes bytestrings to stdout/stderr, rather than unicode (or "wide") strings. It means Python first encodes all unicode data using the current encoding (likely `sys.getdefaultencoding()`).

If you want to get at stdout/stderr as unicode data, you must decode it by yourself using the right encoding.

Your favourite C/C++ library certainly has what it takes to do that.