# Use u'string' on string stored as variable in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

As a French user of Python 2.7, I'm trying to properly print strings containing accents such as "é", "è", "à", etc. in the Python console.

I already know the trick of using u before the explicit value of a string, such as :

```
print(u'Université')
```

which properly prints the last character.

Now, my question is: how can I do the same for a string that is stored as a variable?

Indeed, I know that I could do the following:

```
mystring = u'Université'
print(mystring)
```

but the problem is that the value of `mystring` is bound to be passed into a SQL query (using `psycopg2`), and therefore I can't afford to store the `u` inside the value of `mystring`.

so how could I do something like 
"print the unicode value of `mystring`" ?

Comment: `u'...'` creates an object of type `unicode`. Your `mystring` object is **already* such an object; it's not the `print()` function that turns it into something else.

Comment: Most SQL database adapters can give you Unicode string objects directly, no need to convert. For `str` objects (byte strings), you need to decode from bytes to Unicode. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html for a great article on the subject.

Comment: Then also read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ and the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: I don't really see why this is closed as too broad. We have [the same question for "raw strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605526/how-to-create-raw-string-from-string-variable-in-python), and that one isn't closed.

Comment: does it mean that if I do mystring = u'Université' and then I send a query like "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES "+mystring+";" the value passed to SQL will be understood as 'Université'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `u` sigil is not part of the value, it's just a type indicator.  To convert a string into a Unicode string, you need to know the encoding.

```
unicodestring = mystring.decode('utf-8')  # or 'latin-1' or ... whatever
```

and to print it you typically (in Python 2) need to convert back to whatever the system accepts on the output filehandle:

```
print(unicodestring.encode('utf-8'))  # or 'latin-1' or ... whatever
```

Python 3 clarifies (though not directly simplifies) the situation by keeping Unicode strings and (what is now called) `bytes` objects separate.

Comment: print(mystring.decode('utf-8')) works like a charm for displaying accented characters properly in the console. Thanks.