# Making Python loggers log all stdout and stderr messages

Tags: python, logging, stdout, python-logging, tee

Using the python logging package, and writing a class Log, I'd like to tee stdout and stderr to a log file :

```
log = Log("log.txt")
print "line1"
print "line2"
print >>sys.stderr, "err1"
del log
print "line to screen only"
```

The output log file would contain :

```
16/11/2017 09:51:58 INFO - line1
16/11/2017 09:51:58 INFO - line2
16/11/2017 09:51:58 INFO - err1
```

Any idea how to write this Log class, keeping the advantages of the "logging" package (time-stamps, ...) ?

Comment: You absolutely can not call `log.log(msg)` instead of `print(msg)`?

Comment: No (too many "print" to change ;-) I checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log  (but the other way round).

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware of this, you can add a streamhandler to the logger which will make the logger write to both `log.txt` and `stdout` or `stderr`:
`ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`
`ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`
`log.addHandler(ch)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Popen: Write to stdout AND log file simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535240/python-popen-write-to-stdout-and-log-file-simultaneously)
Have you checked that one as well?

Comment: Honestly, replacing the `print` statements, even if they are many, sounds easier than solving this the wrong way around of attaching a logger to `stdout`.

Answer (score 10):

The *right* way to achieve what you ask is to use Logger object. It gives you much more flexability. This object can be bound to multiple handlers; You need a streamhandler to log message to `sys.stdout` and a file handler to log it to a file. You then both print to the screen and log to a file in a single command.

```
import logging

# create logger 
logger = logging.getLogger('example')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create file handler which logs messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('fh.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler to print to screen
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

Now every call to `logger.info(msg)` will be printed both to the screen, and written to `fh.log` file.

---

There is another way, where you can replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` stream objects. Create a class and customize it ([original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956228/840582)):

```
import sys

class writer(object):
    _fh = None
    _orig_stdout = sys.stdout

   def __init__(self):
       _fh = open('logging.log', 'w')

    def write(self, data):
        fp.write(data)
        _orig_stdout.write(data)

    def flush():
        _orig_stdout.flush()

logger = writer()

sys.stdout = logger
sys.stderr = logger
```

Comment: No. I wish to keep my "print" commands -if possible- , and tee to a log file using the logger advantages. Something like the "multifile class" (shx2's answer) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use the `writer` class then, but I highly recommend you to use logger. If you won't do it now, trust me, you will in the future if you gonna continue developing this code.

Comment: What is `fp` in write method?

Comment: I used the 2nd code in jupyter notebook but a error was raised:`NameError: name '_orig_stdout' is not defined` at `_orig_stdout.flush()`

Answer (score 3):

I made [this package](https://github.com/fx-kirin/py-stdlogging) to do exactly what you said.

```
pip install stdlogging
```

After installed from pip, you can capture any output by logging. But be careful to capture stdout because it's very fragile.

```
import stdlogging
stdlogging.enable(stdout=False, stderror=True)
```