# How to log error information into file when using pyinstaller with --no-console?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

As you may know, if using `pyinstaller` to package python files, there is an option called `no-console`, so all error information and print result will not shown on screen. My question is if there is any other solution that can let me write those error information and even print result into a log file? I know we can use `try-except` in python to catch error, but what if an error I did not catch? I hope there is a way so we can log all stdout and stderr into a file, so we can check it later. Thanks!

Comment: use logging http://techies-world.com/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-logger-in-python/ here is an article that should help you

Comment: Use the python `logging` module as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325975/7306999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a later answer but I solved it with `sys.excepthook`

I set up a logger and an exception hook for all uncaught exceptions like so:

```
def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
   logging.error(
       "Uncaught exception",
       exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
   )
   sys.exit()

def set_up_logger():
    date_time_obj = datetime.now()
    timestamp_str = date_time_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y_%H_%M_%S")
    filename = './Log/crash-{}.log'.format(timestamp_str)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=filename)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
```

Then just call your `set_up_logger` function in your main.
This works for windowed pyinstaller applications.