# Redirecting python version output

Tags: python, linux, centos

How do I redirect the output of python version into a text file in linux?

I tried the following:

python --version > old.txt

The text file is getting created but it is empty.
Simple question, but beginner here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/608639), [How to redirect stderr in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1956142/608639), [Temporarily Redirect stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6796492/608639), [Redirect stderr and stdout in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/608639), etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python version is output to `stderr` rather than `stdout` which is what your command is writing to the file. In order to write the contents of `stderr` you will want to write:
`python --version 2> old.txt`

Comment: Any reason why it gets output to the STDERR stream?

Comment: Not particularly, some programs just prefer to use stderr to print meta-information (as well as the usual warnings and error messages).