How to raise errors but not print to stdout in Python?
I have written a Python script wherein I deal with various warnings and errors via a series of try/except blocks. However, every time a warning/error is encountered it is written to std out.
I looked into options like:
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

and
python -W ignore foo.py

as suggested in posts like this, but this seems to prevent the warnings being raised at all? (Unless I've misunderstood?)
I need the warnings/errors raised so that the script can deal with the data accordingly but I just don't want it printed to stdout or stderr. Is there a way to achieve this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956142/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-python
would this help?

No, unfortunately not. It seems that post is about re-routing it rather than just hiding it? I just want to stop the warnings from being printed to the terminal/console during interactive use. Thanks for the help all the same!

Is that what you are asking about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions

No. From what I can see the post you linked to is detailing how to catch the warnings and deal with them via try and except blocks, which I have done. I just need to stop the warnings from being printed to the console. I.e. raised so that the script can deal with them but hidden from user view
